# Can't stop solr server on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr, websolr

I try to stop `solr` server on Heroku (already have the Websolr $20 addon installed) but I'm not being able to do so.

```
$ heroku run rake sunspot:solr:stop
Running `rake sunspot:solr:stop` attached to terminal... up, run.1
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.9) (6b20-1.9.9-0ubuntu1~10.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
rake aborted!
No PID file at /app/solr/pids/production/sunspot-solr-production.pid

Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:stop
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `heroku run`, you're asking Heroku to spin up a new dyno. You're then telling this new dyno to run a `rake` task to stop Solr -- but it's not running Solr, it's a brand new dyno on a totally different server, and it's only running the rake task to stop Solr.

You only have a few ways to communicate with a dyno once it's launched:

- through the port it's bound to, if any;
- through a service it's connected to (e.g. a database or message broker); or
- by asking Heroku to stop it, via scaling, deploying a new release, or via `ps:stop`.

You can get a list of the processes your application is running via `heroku ps`. (Presumably this list will include the Solr instance you're trying to stop.) You can terminate any of these processes with `heroku ps:stop <process name>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the index, you should remove the addon.   There is no way to pause addons.